# Create ORCFile outside mapreduce

Tags: hive

I'm using the hadoop java api to create an ORCFile outside of a mapreduce job.  The Writer class for ORCFiles have a method addRow(Object row).  My question is what type should I use for the "row" parameter if I want to be able to query this file using hive?

https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/io/orc/Writer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating ORC files in java is mostly a question of writing a lot of boilerplate code. If you look at the apache-orc test files, you can get a good sense of how to do so. I just released an open-source library that takes care of all the boilerplate using runtime code generation and makes it trivial to serialize java objects to ORC. The library is available via [github](http://github.com/eclecticlogic/eclectic-orc). The library is called eclectic-orc.